# Confusion with Norton's equivalent

Tags: amplifier, thevenin, small-signal, norton

I was trying to find Norton's equivalent for the following circuit from A to B:
[image: The circuit in question.]

So I decided to start by using the fact that \$R_{th}=V_{OC}/I_{SC}\$, and found out that \$V_{OC}=0\$ so I decided to find \$I_{SC}\$ (\$I_{n}\$ in the diagram) and thus short-circuited the terminals to arrive at the second circuit shown, and it seems like \$I_{SC}\$ can take infinite values.

I know that there are other ways to find \$R_{th}\$, that's what I did in the end nonetheless. However I rather expected to find \$I_{SC}\$ to be zero because \$R_{th}\$ is constant, so I would like to know if anything went wrong here. I'm also a little bit confused because I'm not sure about whether I should include a ground terminal in the second circuit because I don't know how to define \$V_{s}\$ otherwise.

Comment: How did you find Voc = 0? Without numbers it is certainly not 0.

Comment: When A-B is an open circuit, zero current flows through \$R_{s}\$ and thus \$V_{s}=0\$ so the dependent source is an open circuit and zero current flows through \$r_{o2}\$

Comment: If Vs is 0 then you don't have a circuit to simplify. Vs needs to have a value and probably does.